# Unity3D Issue with Xbox One controller triggers on Windows 10

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-10, virtual-reality, xbox-one

I recently upgraded my machine from Windows 8 to Windows 10. With Windows 8, the Xbox One controller worked perfectly with my Unity project. However, now that I upgraded my operating system, the trigger axis (3rd axis) always returns a value of 1, which is the maximum value. In my project, the triggers are used to fly up and down, so this issue causes my character to fly upwards endlessly.

In the input manager, the values I have assigned for the 3rd axis are:
- Gravity: 0
- Dead: 0.2
- Sensitivity: 1
These values worked fine previously

Additional information / variables:
- My project uses virtual reality. In order to use the Oculus Rift with Windows 10, I had to upgrade to the Oculus 0.7 SDK/Runtime. 
- My machine has a GeForce GTX 980 Ti graphics card, and I upgraded to the GeForce Game Ready Driver Version 359.06 when I installed Windows 10. 
- My Xbox controller drivers are up to date

My assumption is that this issue is caused by the Windows 10 Xbox One driver. Does anyone else have any ideas what could be causing the problem? Or has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We saw a similar issue - controller worked fine in Win8 but after upgrading the game kept reading axis-based inputs as always down. A controller update fixed it for us:

1. Open Device Manager
2. Right Click "Xbox One Controller"
3. Select Update Driver Software
4. Browse on my PC
5. Let me pick from a list
6. Select "Microsoft Xbox One Controller"